# Get map viewer bounding box in pixels

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a Zoomify source layer and I need to retrieve the position (top, left, width, height and rotate angle) of the rectangle (the red one from the image bellow) that bounds the visible tiles.

Bellow you can see an example: I have two maps with different zoom levels: level 0 with only one tile and level 1 with four tiles.

[image: more details]

Notice that the user are allowed to pan, zoom or rotate the map. Please advice.

If needed, I'm using OpenLayers 3.6.

Comment: Assuming you have the coordinates of the red rectangle, you can get the pixel position with [map.getPixelFromCoordinate()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getPixelFromCoordinate). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The red rectangle is not real, it is the bounding box that keeps all the visible tiles from the map, so in fact I need the coordinates of the first tile (left top corner), the width and height of all tiles and the rotation angle of the view.

Comment: I do have the size of the image at maximum zoom and I think that the width and the height of the current view can be calculated at runtime with the following formula: size = maxSize / pow (2, maxZoom - zoom). I think also the rotation angle can be retrieved from the map with view.getRotation

Comment: But when defining your Zoomify layer, you set an extent. And isn't this extent the extent of the red rectangle?

Comment: It seems that map.getPixelFromCoordinate(0,0) solves a part of my issue, at least the part with the starting point. I have made a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/1zo8r5Lp/8/. The width and the height of the bounding box seems wrong and there are some issues when you rotate the map with the starting point.